# SUID exploit and patch

Tags: unix, privileges

I am working on a SUID root binary 'app' that runs a system("ls -la /dir") command and managed to exploit it by writing a malicious ls to get root and changing my user's environment path to set it to higher priority than the kernel's one.

I noticed that executing it as user returns me root shell while executing it with sudo "./example" uses root's path and simply lists the files in dir. As far as i know setuid inherits owner's (in this case root) privileges to user and sudo executes as root.

What are such vulnerabilities called ? How would an app developer patch it? I there any way i can force user's to use sudo ./app to execute a program?

Comment: System wise setting file permissions so only root and the root group (or similar) can execute it.  Lazy coding way check UID/GID of user when it first starts (if not already root complain and exit).  Better coding way - fix it so that user input can't trigger a buffer overflow.  And I'd REALLY think about writing things that require SUID, etc. until you understand it a little better.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change app to use an absolute path for the commands it runs. For example:

```
system("/bin/ls -la /dir");
```

Even if the users use the sudo command to execute it, there are sudo arguments they can use (--preserve-env) to preserve their own PATH.

If you want the users to run app using sudo, then there's no need for the binary to be SUID root.